# The Finder can’t complete the operation because some data can’t be read or written. (Error code -36)

Tags: macos

I have downloaded NFS-The Run, 16gb file over the torrent on my mac. Now I want to move it to my portable hard-disk (1TB NTFS). Its giving me an error after transferring 8.3GB ie:

***The Finder can’t complete the operation because some data can’t be read or written.***

Any suggestion?

Comment: I don't think anyone is willing to help you pirate software/games. As for fixing your problem, go buy the game instead of stealing it. Problem solved.

Comment: @cksum seems like being honest is a crime in the world :P

Comment: Being honest is not a crime, but being honest about a crime does not prevent you from being considered guilty.

Comment: @patrix I am not denying that. But the point is there are several other questions in the community where people are doing all these things.. like jailbreaking their iphone. Its not legal. So why those questions are answered?

Comment: Jailbreaking is not a crime (at least in most countries around the globe)

Comment: @patrix ok.. its fine. I am using terminal and it worked for me. Posted my answer. Have fun :) Chill dude :) Time to drive the car :)

Comment: As per the FAQs, questions involving pirated software are off topic. Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not able to figure out the finder things so I just copied via terminal

```
 cp -R <fileorfolder> /Volumes/<share>/<fileorfolder>
```